# how to handle delay with setting useState with API data

Tags: reactjs

I am not the first one to have this problem.

but sadly, nothing of what i saw is working for me.

I wanna get data from API.
use the data to call another API.

and than return the data in

or whatever.

so what happens is, the first fetch is going fine. im trying to set it inside a state.

but when the SECOND API runs, the STATE i need, is still empty... it hasnt been updated.

so the component cant render something that doesnt exist. so it crashes.

and also, something here causes multiple renders... 
here is the code:

```
const SecondDisplay = () => {

    const [firstData, setFirstData] = useState("")
    const [secondData, setSecondData] = useState("")
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState("")
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            // getLocation(32.0853, 34.7818)
            fetch(`https://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search?apikey=AZvK08ugMNLlAGAwDD9GQGj108Tm8OIP&q=${position.coords.latitude}%2C${position.coords.longitude}&language=en-us&details=false&toplevel=false`)
            .then(res => {
                if(!res.ok){
                    throw Error("Sorry, something went wrong. please try again later.")
                }
                return res.json()
            })
            .then(data => {
                setFirstData({key: data.Key, name: data.AdministrativeArea.EnglishName})  
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setErrors(error.message)
                setLoading(false)
             })
            })
          }, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if(firstData !== ""){
        third(firstData.key)
    }
}, [firstData])




let third = key => {
    
    fetch(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/${key}?apikey=AZvK08ugMNLlAGAwDD9GQGj108Tm8OIP&language=en-us&details=true HTTP/1.1`)
    .then(res => {
        if(!res.ok){
            throw Error("Sorry, something went wrong. please try again later.")
        }
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
        setSecondData(data)
        setLoading(false)
    })
    .catch(error => {
    setErrors(error.message)
    setLoading(false)
    })
    }


return(<p>{secondData.blabla}</p>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a single `useEffect()` hook, and simply continue the promise chain once you get the response from the first request.

Here's a simplified example:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) throw Error(msg)
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    setFirstData(data)
    return fetch(secondUrl, paramsBasedOn(data))
  })
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) throw Error(msg)
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    setSecondData(data)
  })
  .catch(err => setError(err.message))
```